# JSON.parse issue on long json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

What's wrong in this:

```
var stringinsta=JSON.parse({ "access_token":"129261**5ea59a4da481c65",
                                    "user":{
                                             "username":"carlos_bellesso",
                                             "bio":"",
                                             "website":"",
                                             "profile_picture":"http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_12921998589647.jpg",
                                             "full_name":"","id":"1296618"}
                                              } );
```

The error is: unexpected token o.

Comment: `JSON.parse()` expects a string. You don't give it a string. You give it an object. Its description is `[object Object]`, which the routine tries to parse as an array but it fails to do so, since the `o` is not a valid character in that context. **Think** and **add quotes** as necessary.

Answer (score 5):

It's not working because you pass an object to `JSON.parse()` but it expects a json string -> You already have the object so theres not need to parse anything.

If you want to convert an object to a json string, then use `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: I've obtained by stringify this json passed to parse

Comment: @user1938193 that's not a sentence (at least it's not meaningful).